# How to filter based on equality between several columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data frame similar to the one below.
And I want to filter it, grouping by product, that I would only keep the rows where month >= start_month for the year == start_year. But for the years after I need to retain all months.

```
product year month start_year start_month
A       2015   1     2015        10
A       2015   2     2015        10
A       2015   3     2015        10
A       2015   4     2015        10
A       2015   5     2015        10
A       2015   6     2015        10
A       2015   7     2015        10
A       2015   8     2015        10
A       2015   9     2015        10
A       2015   10     2015       10
A       2015   11     2015       10
A       2015   12     2015       10
A       2016   1     2015        10 
A       2016   2     2015        10
A       2016   3     2015        10
A       2016   4     2015        10
...
B       2015   1     2015        11
B       2015   2     2015        11
...
```

I have tried:

```
  df <- df %>%
  group_by(product) %>% 
  filter(month >= start_month)
```

But this filters months in the following years too.

So the final results should look like this:

```
product year month start_year start_month
A       2015   10     2015       10
A       2015   11     2015       10
A       2015   12     2015       10
A       2016   1     2015        10 
A       2016   2     2015        10
A       2016   3     2015        10
A       2016   4     2015        10
...
A       2018   12    2015        10
...
```

Comment: Have you tried actually adding your conditions within the `filter` call e.g `filter(month >= start_month & year == start_year`?

Comment: Yes, but then it just retains the rows for the first year and completely eliminates the following years and months.

Comment: @NelsonGon I think you want `filter(month >= start_month | year > start_year)`?

Comment: @duckmayr Seems like that does the job.

Comment: Yes it works, such an easy fix, thanks!